# Placing JTextFields in a JFrame of a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, layout-manager

I have:

```
public class BaseStationFrame1 extends JFrame
{

    JButton activateButton;
    JButton deactivateButton;
    BaseStation bs;

    JTextField networkIdField;
    JTextField portField;



    public BaseStationFrame1(BaseStation _bs){

        bs = _bs;

        setTitle("Base Station");
        setSize(600,500); 
        setLocation(100,200);  
        setVisible(true);

        activateButton = new JButton("Activate");
        deactivateButton = new JButton("Deactivate");
        Container content = this.getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        content.add(activateButton);
        content.add(deactivateButton);

        networkIdField = new JTextField("networkId : "+ bs.getNetworkId());
        networkIdField.setEditable(false);

        content.add(networkIdField);

        portField = new JTextField("portId : "+ bs.getPort());
        portField.setEditable(false);

        content.add(portField);}
    }
```

My problem is that i don't want the two TextFields to appear on the right of `Activate` and `Deactivate` buttons but below them. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify your layout manager, like this:

```
content.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
```

That would use the [Grid Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)  to establish a grid with 2 columns and 2 rows, that your components would then be placed in.

The layout manager you are currently using, [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html), only adds contents onto the end of the current row.  it will wrap around once it reaches the constrained edge of the pane, though. 
You should also check the other layout managers  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

You could alternatively use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) , but you will have to specify a `GridBagConstraints` object you then add alongside the individual elements, like so:

```
content.add(networkIdField, gridConstraints);
```

see more on that in the linked tutorial.

Comment: +1 `GridLayout` also nests nicely, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513).

Answer (score -1):

can I suggest that you use a Null Layout for the parent component?

setLayout(null);

then use a setBounds(xPos,yPos, Width, Height);

to position the components on the panel etc?

Doing this will prevent Java's UI Manager to manage the components to the Frame, Panel etc.

That seems to be the easiest and less painful way.

Regards

Comment: -1 for null layout suggestion. Layout manages exist for a reason.

Comment: Ok, thought it would be the easiest, then you can try GridBagLayout which will also require you to set rows and Columns to position the component. [GridBagLayout](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gridBagLayout&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2Flayout%2Fgridbag.html&ei=PSThTqm8Eu-imQXq7eH0BA&usg=AFQjCNHKarD9oHgot_7Z7zHPurIFKvX56w&sig2=8kNOBW2nvBxgMdq35mQOKA&cad=rja). It might work, but with a lot of trouble.